# Doctrine2 column type integer of length 255 doesn't apply to DB

Tags: database, integer, doctrine-orm

I'm using Doctrine 2 for my DB and I'm currently trying to set a length for one of my column that has an "integer" type but it just doesn't seem to be taken.

```
/** @Column(type="integer", length=255) */
protected $number;
```

When I check my database it still says "int(11)" instead of "int(255)". I haven't found anyone experiencing that problem on google or maybe my keywords ain't working so good. I've seen a few example of people using length=XXX and not complaining about it so I thought it would be the way to go but so far no good...

I'm always dropping/rebuilding the whole DB and proxies etc so I doubt it comes from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you cannot have such a big `INT` in MySQL.

Try using the type `BIGINT` instead, it goes from -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807 (signed) or from 0 to 18446744073709551615 (unsigned).

Doctrine version:

```
/** @Column(type="bigint") */
protected $number;
```

[Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html)

Comment: The length attribute implies width. You can have such a big number for `INT` width because it has nothing to do with the range of int.

Comment: I agree with @meze. This answere is bogus.

Answer (score 0):

Seen this misunderstanding very often. So, to clarify @meze (see the comments above).

The `size` of any MySQL integer type is about the `display width` which comes into play with `ZEROFILL`.

A select on a `ZEROFILL` column leads to a value at least left padded with `0` up to the `size` / `display width` of the column.

A simple example to explain it fully. Look at the returned output.

```
CREATE TABLE `foo`
(
    `col_1`    INT(1),
    `col_1_Z`  INT(1) ZEROFILL,
    `col_11`   INT(11),
    `col_11_Z` INT(11) ZEROFILL
);

INSERT INTO `foo`
VALUES
    (42, 42, 42, 42);

SELECT
    col_1,
    col_1_Z,
    col_11,
    col_11_Z
FROM
    `foo`;

/* returned output */

|       col_1 |     col_1_Z |      col_11 |    col_11_Z |
|-------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|
|          42 |          42 |          42 | 00000000042 |
```